# Jekyll installation on macOS Mojave 10.14

Tags: ruby, macos, installation, rubygems, jekyll

Can anyone provide me the complete guide of installing jekyll in the latest macOS 10.14?

As you might know that the directory is protected in macOS and returns error

```
While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0 directory.
```

I have tried all the methods available on internet like managing multiple versions of ruby using `rbenv` or exporting path `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"` to the .bashrc file.`

None of the methods seem to be working for me. Please provide step by step installation guide of `jekyll` on macOS.